# how to get the latest file in the folder

Tags: jython

i have written the code to retrieve and file and time it got created by i just want to get the latest file name created. Please suggest how can i do that in jython .

```
 import os
    import glob
    import time
    folder='C:/xml'
    for folder in glob.glob(folder):
        for file in glob.glob(folder+'/*.xml'):
            stats=os.stat(file)
            print file ,time.ctime(stats[8])
```

Thanks again for all your help

I have re-modified the codes as suggested and i am not getting the right answer , Please suggest what mistake i am doing.

```
import os
import glob
import time
folder='C:/xml'
for x in glob.glob(folder+"/*.xml"):
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime)=os.stat(x)
    time1=time.ctime(mtime)
    for z in glob.glob(folder+"/*.xml"):
        (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime)=os.stat(z)
        time2=time.ctime(mtime)
        if (time1>time2):
            new_file=x
            new_time=time1
        else:
            new_file=z
            new_time=time2

print new_file,new_time
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two variables to keep track of the name and time of the latest file found so far. Whenever you find a *later* file, update both variables. When your loop is done, the variables will contain the name and time of the latest file.

I'm not quite sure why you have two nested loops in your example code; if you're looking for all `*.xml` files in the given directory, you only need one loop.

A Pythonic solution might be something like:

```
folder = "C:/xml"
print max((os.stat(x)[8], x) for x in glob.glob(folder+"/*.xml"))
```

If you choose the `max()` solution, be sure to consider the case where there are *no* `*.xml` files in your directory.

Comment: I have remodified the code  but iam not getting the right answer , any suggestion .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kdev: Again, why do you have *two* nested loops? One should be sufficient. Try writing your code with one loop and see if that helps.